# How can I change this pl/sql to a function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I'm following through exercises in a booklet as I am just learning PL/SQL in Oracle and it wants me to turn this into a function and I have no idea how I could as it's not a stored procedure at least I don't think it is and there are no calculations to be done... any ideas what I'm supposed to do?

```
DECLARE
my_stdate LEASE.STDATE%TYPE;
my_enddate LEASE.ENDDATE%TYPE;
my_property_no LEASE.PROPERTY_NO%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT stdate, enddate, property_no
INTO my_stdate, my_enddate, my_property_no
FROM lease
WHERE lease_no = '&enter_lease_no';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Property '||my_property_no||' was leased from '||my_stdate||' and '||my_enddate);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution variable `&enter_lease_no` is the input and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(...)` is the PL/SQL anonymous block's output.

To make it a function, pass the lease number in as a argument (instead of a substitution variable) and return the string value that is to be output.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test_function(
  enter_lease_no IN LEASE.LEASE_NO%TYPE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  my_stdate      LEASE.STDATE%TYPE;
  my_enddate     LEASE.ENDDATE%TYPE;
  my_property_no LEASE.PROPERTY_NO%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT stdate, enddate, property_no
  INTO my_stdate, my_enddate, my_property_no
  FROM lease
  WHERE lease_no = enter_lease_no;

  RETURN 'Property '||my_property_no||' was leased from '||my_stdate||' and '||my_enddate;
END;
/
```

Which can then be called using:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( test_function( '&enter_lease_no' ) );
END;
/
```

Comment: I think it worth pointing out that the function could also be used in a straight SQL query:  SELECT TEST_FUNCTION('&enter_lease_no') from dual. (Lest the beginner think your example is the only way to call a function).  Also worth pointing out that in either example, the call to the function is still depending on a substitution variable as input, and 1) that substitution variable is a sqlplus construct and 2) there are other ways of supplying that value.   All, just so the OP understands that there are more ways of _using_ the function than just these simple examples.  :-)